Teknic ClearCore motor controller - I'm completely lost
I'm new to robotics and feel like I'm misunderstanding something really simple, but I don't know what.  Very lost, could use some direction.
I have a Teknic ClearCore motor controller, and a few ClearPath motors.
I'm unable to get any of the example programs to run using the Arduino IDE wrapper available in their library (https://teknic-inc.github.io/ClearCore-library/).  I can, however, use the Arduino example library to make one of the LEDs blink ... so I know communication is at least working.
Resources are hard to find.  I cannot find an example of how to use this ecosystem from a user's point of view such as a youtube video or a blog.
Is there a community devoted to these motors?  Where can I find other users?

your questions are not about robotics... please edit your post ... ask about the problem you are facing ... describe what you have done ... include any code you are trying to run

I asked a question. It's the last thing I wrote.

those are not questions about a robotics problem

I'm an Applications Engineer with Teknic and came across your post. It's hard to say what is happening with your software installation but I am confident we can help you work this out quickly. Could you please repost your question along with your contact information on our website at https://teknic.com/contact/ ? Your technical support request will be routed to an applications engineer who should be able to help you.

I will try that, thank you.
